# Custom font in rdlc gets messed up on special characters

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm having a strange problem and i cannot figure out, where it is coming from.

We are using MS ReportViewer (tried both 14 and 15) to generate PDF from RDLC. Now I have two custom fonts, both installed on my test system, where the PDFs are generated. Let's call them Hell43 and Hell55 (it's actually Helvetica...[] but as it is giving me hell hat the moment, let's stick with hell[]).

Now Hell43 is HelveticaNeueLt Pro 43 LtEx
and Hell55 is HelveticaNeueLt Pro 55 Roman

The issue is the following: When generating the PDF and opening with Adobe Acrobat everything written in Hell55 gets messed up (no real characters), when there are special characters used in the textbox in the RDLC. You can place two textboxes using Hell55 side by side, the one with special characters will get messed up:

[image: Hell55 including special characters (ä, µ, ...)]

while the same text using Hell43 will work out fine:

[image: Hell43 using using special character]

No what is strange:
1. This happens only when opening with Adobe Acrobat - Sumatra PDF seems to work. Chrome, Edge, IE only mess up the special characters, not the whole line.
2. When looking at the document properties in Adobe Acrobat it seems, that Hell55 doesn't get embedded into the PDF.

[image: Font properties in document]

[image: Error only claims Bold is missing?]

I did read some posts about visibilty-property on certain elements messing up font embedding, but I tried with Hell43 to hide one single element, and look if I could reproduce the behavior for the font - but couldn't.
Further: When looking at the character set, the needed characters should be there (when creating the RDLC in design mode, the characters are displayed correctly). And then when looking at the font properties in windows the two fonts have the same properties, and should be embeddable:

[image: FontFamily properties]

[image: Upper one is Hell43]

Could maybe the weights cause the problem? I tried setting it from bold to normal, but that didn't solve it.
3. Updating from MS ReportViewer version 14 to 15 didn't solve anything.

Now I am a little short on things to test. Any suggestions? Thanks and thanks and thanks in advance.

Comment: fonts from hell :)
what are the special characters you're talking about: just umlauts, or some rare unicode glyphs?

Comment: It’s all kind of international stuff, Umlaute as well as Turkish characters. For example this thingy: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/015f/index.htm